# How to get from $-1\le\frac{1}{2a}\le1$ this $-1\ge2a\ge1 $?

Tags: inequality

How to get from $-1\le\frac{1}{2a}\le1$ this $-1\ge2a\ge1 $ ?

I can see the connection, I tried doing $/^{-1}$, but the $\le$ sign does not change to $\ge$, or does it? Why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't get that, since it would mean $-1\geq 1$. $a\geq b\geq c$ means $a\geq b$ *and* $b\geq c$...

Comment: Somebody should tell you that what you wrote is wrong. Read it carefully, it implies $-1\ge 1$.

Comment: Well that's what I thought. That was the answer to my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804152/trigonometry-math-problem, and I knew that something went wrong here, but since I am no math expert I did not want to claim that that is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$-1\le\frac{1}{2a}\le1\iff \frac{1}{2|a|}\le1\iff \frac12\le |a|\iff \left(a\le -\frac12\right)\lor \left(a\ge\frac12\right) \iff \left(2a\le -1\right)\lor \left(2a\ge1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac1b\le1\iff\frac1b-1\le0\iff\frac{1-b}b\le0\iff\frac{b-1}b\ge0$$

If $b>0, b-1\ge0\iff b\ge1\implies b\ge1$

if $b<0,b-1\le0\iff b\le1\implies b<0$

Answer (score 1):

When you have an inequality such as $a < b$ and you apply a strictly decreasing function $f(x)$ to both sides of the equation you then have $f(b) > f(a)$. One example of this is with negation. If $a < b$ then $-b > -a$ because $f(x) = -x$ is a decreasing function.

If the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is also decreasing on our interval then $a > b$ implies $\frac{1}{b} > \frac{1}{a}$.

The easiest way to go about your problem is to break it up into two inequalities showing that $-1 \leq \frac{1}{2a}$ implies $-1 \geq 2a$ and $\frac{1}{2a} \leq 1$ implies $2a \geq 1$.

You can't have both inequalities satisfied at the same time so one or the other must be satisfied.

A "smarter" way of going after this problem would be to write $\left|\frac{1}{2a}\right| \leq 1$ implies $|2a| > 1$. The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$ so we can modify our problem so that we are only dealing with positive numbers which allows us to use the properties of decreasing functions for our inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it "changes". If $a\leq b$ then $\frac{1}{a}\geq \frac{1}{b}$ (by dividing $ab$ both sides). The same way for, if $\frac{1}{2a}\leq 1$ then $2a\geq 1$ and if $\frac{1}{2a}\geq -1$ then $2a\leq -1$.